# To keep track of the minimum height of a tree from nodes of a graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

I was trying to solve the algorithm question from Leetcode; called "[Minimum Height Trees](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-height-trees/)".

What I tried was using 2-colors(visited, not visited yet) then recursively call a helper function to increment height. But I am slightly stuck at almost the final step where I commented out. I am unable to think of a way to specify under which condition I should check the height.

The below is my code. If anyone can help me out, I appreciate. 
Thank you.

```java
class Solution {
    enum Color{
        White,Grey;
    }
    public List<Integer> findMinHeightTrees(int n, int[][] edges) {
        int minHeight = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        List<List<Integer>> adjLists = buildGraph(n, edges);
        List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        Color[] visited = new Color[n];
        Arrays.fill(visited, Color.White);

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            calculateHeight(adjLists, i, edges, visited, 0, ret);
        }

        return ret;

    }
        private List<List<Integer>> buildGraph(int n, int[][] edges){
            List<List<Integer>> adjLists = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                adjLists.add(new ArrayList<>());
            }
            for(int[] node : edges){
                int v = node[0], u = node[1];
                adjLists.get(u).add(v);
                adjLists.get(v).add(u); 
            }
            return adjLists;
        }
        private void calculateHeight(List<List<Integer>> adjLists, int start, int[][] edges, Color[] visited, int height, List<Integer> ret){
            /* I feel like I miss some conditions here but any idea is not top on my head for a week */
            if(visited[start] == Color.Grey)
                return;
            visited[start] = Color.Grey;
            for(int v : adjLists.get(start)){
                calculateHeight(adjLists, v, edges, visited, height+1, ret);
            }
            visited[start] = Color.White;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what's your goal but I think your method calculateHeight is wrong. It seems for every vertex (findMinHeightTree) you compute its associated length, and you want to reuse some cache for the already computed nodes. However you can't have cycles so for your current vertex, if the minimal height tree passed through your current one, it is invalid and not to be considered.
A possibility  is to consider an adjency matrix and power it until (for each line i) a line of zero appears which means the longest path of line i has been reached

Comment: edit: disregard my approach with the adjency matrix. For the second example with edges [0,1], [1,3] a path of length 2 is [0,3,1] but a path of length 3 would be [0,3,1,3] which is not valid but considered via adjency matrix. The standard way seem to (by definition) consider the [center of the graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_center#cite_note-P-6), which can be adressed by [Floyd Warshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)

Comment: I actually doubt about the possibility of applying Floyd Warshall on the tree because it is undirected (should it be directed, we'd have a DAG on which we can take the negative weights but here I don't see it)

Answer (score 0):

Finding the minimum height trees is to find the center of the tree (composed of one or two vertices)

A possible implementation (from [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/centers-of-a-tree)) is to remove at every steps the "leaves".

Hopefully at the end, there is only the center left.

Below an example in js

```js
// https://www.tutorialspoint.com/centers-of-a-tree
function buildAdjencyList (edges) {
  return edges.reduce((dic, [from, to]) => {
    dic.set(from, (dic.get(from) || new Set()).add(to))
    dic.set(to, (dic.get(to) || new Set()).add(from))
    return dic
  }, new Map())
}
function simplify (G) {
  const verticesToDelete = []
  for (let [k,v] of G) {
    if (v.size == 1) {
      G.delete(k)
      verticesToDelete.push(k)
    }
  }
  for (let [k,v] of G) {
    verticesToDelete.forEach(del => {
      if (v.has(del)) {
        v.delete(del)
      }
    })
  }
}
function dump(G){
  for(let [k,v] of G){
    console.log(k, '->', JSON.stringify([...v]))
  }
}
function run(edges){
  const G = buildAdjencyList(edges)
  while(true){
    const keys = [...G.keys()]
    simplify(G)
    // handles bicentral tree
    if(G.size === 0) {
      return keys
    }
    // handles central tree
    if(G.size === 1) {
      return [...G.keys()]
    }
    console.log('iter')
    dump(G)
  }
}

console.log('bicentral', run([[0, 1], [1, 2], [3, 2], [2, 4], [2, 5],[5,6],[6,7]]))
console.log('central', run([[0, 1], [1, 2]]))
```